# Calculate $E[\max(Y-k,0)]$ where $Y = e^X$ and $X$ is normally distributed

Tags: probability-theory

I'm having trouble with the following problem:
Let X be normally distributed with mean $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ and variance $\sigma^2 > 0$. Let $k > 0$ be a constant, and define the random variable $Y$ by $Y = e^X$. Calculate $E[\max(Y-K,0)]$.

I need to express the answer in terms of $\Phi$ (the cumulative distribution function for the standard normal) and the input parameters.

My attempt:
Define the indicator random variable
$$
\begin{equation}
 I_{Y \ge k} :=
  \begin{cases}
  1 & Y \ge k \\
  0 & Y < k
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$

Then, the expression simplifies to $E[(Y-k)I_{Y\ge k}] = E[YI_{Y\ge k}] - kE[I_{Y\ge k}]$. Since I previously calculated the value of $P(Y \ge k)$, we have k$E[I_{Y\ge k}] = kP(Y \ge k)$. However, I'm having trouble evaluating $E[YI_{Y\ge k}]$.
Since $Y = e^X$, we have $E[YI_{Y\ge k}] = E[e^XI_{Y\ge k}] = \int_{\log k}^\infty e^sf_X(s)ds$. But after expanding, I get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\int_{\log k}^\infty \exp(x - \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2})dx$, and I'm not sure this is integrable.

Have I done something wrong? Is there a simpler approach? I think I could use a hint.

Comment: This is the formula for the value of a call option, calculated by using censored distributions. See for instance Example 24 on page 70 of http://www.mathstatica.com/book/Rose_and_Smith_2002edition_Chapter2.pdf

Comment: Complete the square in the exponential.